# Dependency Setup and App pre-preperation in SwiftUI 2.0

Tags: swift, swiftui

Since SwiftUI 2.0 does not have an `AppDelegate` anymore i was wondering where i'm supposed to prepare e.g. my `DependencyManager` (<- is static)?

Previously i set it up in the AppDelegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like:

```swift
DependencyManager.set(dependency: DummyClass())
```

I thought one has to do it in the `@main struct ...: App` now but `DependencyManager` is unknown there and in the `Scene` itself it results in the following error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'Scene'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it

```
@main
struct Demo_SwiftUI2App1: App {

    init() {
        DependencyManager.set(dependency: DummyClass())    // << here !!
    }

    var body: some Scene {
      // ... other code here
```

or

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        DependencyManager.set(dependency: DummyClass()) // << here !!
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct Demo_SwiftUI2App2: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
       // ... other code here
```

first variant is called before second, just in case.

Comment: Wow, calling the `init`. So easy actually, just didn't come to my mind that there is an init cause it's SwiftUI. Thanks!